# How to prove that $f_n(x) = (\frac{4}{4+x^2})^n$ can be approximated to $e^{-\frac{nx^2}{4}}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: functions

I want to prove the question above, I have tried to rewrite $f_n(x)$ as 
$ f_n(x) = (1+\frac{x^2}{4})^{-n} $, but it is approximated to $e^{-\frac{nx^2}{4}}$ only when $x \rightarrow 0$. Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: A sequence depending on $n$ cannot converge to something depending on $n$ if $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly used the word `` converge'', it may be more proper to use the word `` approximate''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $n$ we have $(\frac 4 {4+x^{2}})^{n}=e^{-n \ln (1+\frac {x^{2}} 4)}$. We have $\ln (1+t) =t+O(t^{2})$ as $t \to 0$. So $(\frac 4 {4+x^{2}})^{n}$ can be approximated by $e^{-nx^{2}/4}$. However this approximation is **not uniform** in $n$. It is valid only for fixed $n$.

Comment: Must be $\ln(1+t)=t+o(t)$.

Comment: @thing Thank you. I wanted to type $0(t^{2})$.

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems that when $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$, the approximation still holds.